# How to fill the space only when defined value difference is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, fill

I want to fill the space between DI+ and DI- with a color, but only when the difference between their values they currently have are bigger then, for example, 20.

I know how to fill them, but I don't know how to add this condition with the value, can someone help please?

```
p1 = plot(plus, color = color.gray)
p2 = plot(minus, color = color.yellow)
fill(p1, p2, color = plus > minus ? color.lime : color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created inputs for plus and minus for testing purposes but this does what you are looking for using the ternary operator to chose which color will be used.

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
plus = input.int(300)
minus = input.int(280)
fillColor = plus - minus >= 20 ? color.lime : minus - plus >= 20 ? color.red : color.new(color.white,100)
p1 = plot(plus, color = color.gray)
p2 = plot(minus, color = color.yellow)
fill(p1, p2, color = fillColor)
```